# Raspbian image creation: install plugins with the Raspbian version of Chromium?

Tags: raspbian, image, chromium, plugins

Is there a away to install pre-defined plugins with the Raspbian version of Chromium?

I have been looking at editing and [the image creator tool](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen/blob/dev/stage3/00-install-packages/00-packages#L10) to include chromium with [metamask](https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension) by editing Stage 3.

Chromium is installed at [stage 3](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/pi-gen/blob/dev/stage3/00-install-packages/00-packages#L10). which results in

```
apt-get chromium-browser rpi-chromium-mods
```

**Is there a way to edit this command in such a way that the Metamask plugin is installed with chromium?**

Note I can get Metamask to install with Chromium ok if I manually install it, but installing from command line would save time.

Other note - I am intending to fork a fork of the image creator - [Diego Losada's Raspbian image creator](https://github.com/diglos/pi-gen)

Answer (score 2):

There is not a package in the repositories that will install a Chrome extension manually.

But this is easy to do - just copy over `~.config/chromium`. Here's how:

1. Create your chromium "master copy". In other words, launch chromium and make all necessary modifications, such as install an extension.
2. Chromium saves all of its configuration (and extensions) to 
   `/home/pi/.config/chromium`. So to make a fresh Raspbian image to ship with those chromium mods pre-installed, just copy `/home/pi/.config/chromium` to the completed Raspbian image.